# Centering both image and text in a div using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to perfectly center both the image and the text below the image in a container using this code

```
<div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center w-50" id="container1">
   <div>
     <img className="border" src="assets/image1.png" alt="" />
     <p className="mt-3">Text below image</p>
   </div>
 <div>
```

but it's not vertically centered it has more space on bottom compared to top

Comment: @zim yup the container has a defined height 50vh

Comment: @Zim sorry it's 50vh.

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://www.codeply.com/p/HFvtClzJtq

Comment: as you can see it's not vertically centered it has more space in the bottom than the top :)

Comment: Are you talking about the margin on the bottom of the paragraph? Remove it with `mb-0`